# How to update a table in snowflake with data from Oracle?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I need to update a table in snowflake by taking data from oracle database.
Is there a way to connect to oracle database from snowflake?
If answer is NO how can i update the table in snowflake using data from oracle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure exactly what you are looking for here.  The best way to get data into Snowflake is via the COPY INTO command, which would then allow you to update the Snowflake table with that data.  If you are looking at ways to keep the 2 systems in-sync, then you might want to look into the various data replication tools that are in the marketplace.  If this is a transactional update, then you can use a connector (ODBC, JDBC, Python, etc.) to update the data from one system to another.  I wouldn't recommend that for bulk updates, though.

Comment: I have a table in oracle with nearly 700 million records. i need to take that data and add those recordsd into a table in snowflake. My exact question is: can i pull that  data from oracle directly into snowflake?  OR Do i need to use any programming language like python to pull from oracle and load into snowflake? Thank you for your quick reply.

Comment: If this is a 1-time thing, then the best method is to pull the data out of Oracle to a flat-file and then COPY INTO Snowflake.  Any ETL tool, python scripting, etc. that you might want to use to automate this on a regular basis should essentially be doing the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways you can integrate your data from oracle to snowflake. If you are familiar with ETL tool you can use any one of them or you can use any program language to extract and load.